Double Contact Chained Ellipses Problem
A few years ago, when I played around with GeoGebra, I came up with the following conjecture.

Conjecture
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq3$. Let $E$ be an ellipse, and let $E_{1}, E_{2}, \dots, E_{n}$ be ellipses each of which lies inside and has double contact with $E$. Suppose that $E_{i}$ is tangent to $E_{i-1}$ and $E_{i+1}$ at $T_{i}$ and $T_{i+1}$, respectively ($i=1, 2, \dots, n$, indices are taken $\mod n$). Let $r_{2i-1}$ be the radius of the incircle of $E_{i}$ (i.e. the center of the circle lies on the major axis of $E_{i}$) touching at $T_{i}$. Similarly, let $r_{2i}$ be the radius of the incircle of $E_{i}$ touching at $T_{i+1}$. Then,
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}r_{2i-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}r_{2i}$$

Unfortunately I cannot prove or disprove this proposition by myself. My numerical experiments on GeoGebra show that the above claim is most likely true, but I am not 100% sure. I even posted this problem on Art of Problem Solving on December 28, 2022, but no solutions are known so far.
Could anyone prove or disprove this statement? Also, if it is true, I wonder if this can be generalize to conics. For example, does the same thing hold if we replace $E$ with degenerate two lines?

Edit:
This problem was inspired by traditional Japanese geometry problems. For example, see J. Marshall Unger, Ellipses in Sangaku Problems. Also inspired by A. V. Akopyan, Geometry in Figures, Second, extended edition, 2017.
For some special cases, this problem is partially solved.
For $n=3$
By applying the Double Contact Theorem, it can be easily shown that the three tangent lines of mutually tangent inner ellipses are concurrent. Let $P$ be the point of concurrency.

Lemma 1
Let $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$ be incircles of an Ellipse $E_{1}$ with centers $O_{1}$, $O_{2}$, respectively. Let $T_{1}$, $T_{2}$ be touchpoints of
$C_{1}$ and $E_{1}$, $C_{2}$ and $E_{1}$, respectively. Let $t_{1}$, $t_{2}$ be the common tangent lines of $C_{1}$ and $E_{1}$, $C_{2}$ and $E_{1}$ through $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$, respectively. Let $P$ be the intersection of $t_{1}$ and $t_{2}$. Then, $$\angle{O_{1}PT_{1}}=\angle{O_{2}PT_{2}}$$. 

This result was proved algebraically. Therefore, $$\dfrac{|PT_{1}|}{|PT_{2}|}=\dfrac{r_{1}}{r_{2}}$$ $$\dfrac{|PT_{2}|}{|PT_{3}|}=\dfrac{r_{3}}{r_{4}}$$ $$\dfrac{|PT_{3}|}{|PT_{1}|}=\dfrac{r_{5}}{r_{6}}$$ By multiplying these equations, we get what we wanted.
When $E$ is a circle
I found the following lemma.

Lemma 2
Let $C$ be a circle, and $E$ be a double contact ellipse inside $C$ with semi-minor axis length $b$. Let $C_{1}$ be an incircle of $E$ with radius $r$ whose center lies on the major axis of $E$. Let $T$ be a touchpoint of $E$ and $C_{1}$. Let the tangent line to $E$ at $T$ cut $C$ at $P$ and $Q$. Let $p:=|TP|, q:=|TQ|$. Then, $$\dfrac{2b}{r}=\sqrt{\dfrac{p}{q}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{q}{p}}$$

This can be derived by a brute force method.
By using this, it can be shown that $$\dfrac{b_{1}}{r_{2}}=\dfrac{b_{2}}{r_{3}}$$where $b_{1}$ is the semi-minor axis length of $E_{1}$, and $b_{2}$ is the semi-minor axis length of $E_{2}$. The same relationship holds for other ellipses $E_{i}$ and $E_{i+1}$, and we are done.

I cannot prove general cases from these lemmas though. At first, I thought I could prove this proposition by using an affine transformation, but then my reasoning turned out to be defective, and I was stuck.

Generalized Question

Generalized Question
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}\wedge n\geq2$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an conic, and let $\mathcal{C_{1}}, \dots, \mathcal{C_{n}}$ be conics each of which has double contact with $\mathcal{C}$. Suppose that $\mathcal{C_{i}}$ is tangent to $\mathcal{C_{i-1}}$ and $\mathcal{C_{i+1}}$ at $T_{i}$ and $T_{i+1}$, respectively ($i=1, \dots, n$, indices are taken $\mod n$). Let $r_{2i-1}$ be the radius of the incircle of $\mathcal{C_{i}}$ (i.e. the center of the circle lies on the major axis of $\mathcal{C_{i}}$) touching at $T_{i}$. Similarly, let $r_{2i}$ be the radius of the incircle of $\mathcal{C_{i}}$ touching at $T_{i+1}$. Then, does the following relationship hold?
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}r_{2i-1}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}r_{2i}$$
Update: No, this does not hold in general. I found an obvious counterexample.



Interesting! ... Please tell us something about the context of this problem. Was it inspired by similar results? Can you prove it for, say, $n=3$? or when the bounding conic is a circle? How did you even go about constructing the five-element chain in your GeoGebra figure?

Constructing this configuration on GeoGebra requires a lot of steps. Yes, this problem was inspired by an traditional Japanese Geometry problem about ellipses. See J. Marshall Unger, "Ellipses in Sangaku Problems". For $n=3$, by using the Double Contact Theorem, it can be easily shown that the three tangent lines of mutually tangent inner ellipses are concurrent. Let $P$ be the point of concurrency. then, $PT_{1}/PT_{2}=r_{1}/r_{2}$, and we are done. When the bounding conic is a circle, yes, I discovered a useful lemma. By using it, it can be proved. I will edit the post if I have some time.

@"I will edit the post if I have some time." ... There's a maxim: Always treat the reader's time as more valuable than your own. It applies in many authorial contexts, but is particularly relevant when asking that reader for help. Here, you clearly have a wealth of knowledge about this very difficult problem; sharing it will save people a great deal of their valuable time starting from scratch and will help them avoid duplicating your effort or re-discovering various things you already know. ... Good luck!

A solution was posted at https://artofproblemsolving.com/.  Would you like it mentioned here?

@brainjam Thank you, I found a solution by a22886 posted on AoPS Geometry Marathon. It would be better to cite / replicate it here as well so that I could accept the answer, and in case the link breaks.

A solution by a22886 was posted on AoPS Geometry Marathon as entry #900.  The entry says "S204" (for "Solution to Problem 204") which, when clicked, reveals the solution.  I'm marking this answer as Community wiki, so it anybody wants to transcribe the solution to this answer, they are welcome to do so.

Edit by K. Miyamoto.
A solution by a22886 posted on AoPS Geometry Marathon
S204

Just about the craziest geometry I've ever done.

Lemma1
For points $A,B$ on ellipse $\omega$, consider the circles $\omega_A,\omega_B$ centered on the longer axis of $\omega$ and tangent to $\omega$ at $A,B$. Say the tangents from $A,B$ to $\omega$ intersects at $C$, then$$\frac{\text{radius of $\omega_A$}}{\text{radius of $\omega_B$}}=\frac{CA}{CB}$$

Proof
Set up a coordinate!



Lemma2
Three ellipses $\omega,\omega_1,\omega_2$ satisfy that (1) $\omega_i$ and $\omega$ are tangent at two points $A_{i1},A_{i2}$, (2) $\omega_1,\omega_2$ are tangent at $X$. Say tangents to $\omega$ at $\omega_{i1},\omega_{i2}$ intersect at $B_i$, and $A_{11}A_{12}\cap A_{21}A_{22}=C$, then$$B_1B_2X\text{ is collinear, and }CX\text{ is tangent to }\omega_{1,2}$$ 

Proof
Suppose $B_1B_2X$ is not collinear and $CX$ is not the tangent.
Let $\ell$ be the tangent to $\omega_{1,2}$ at $X$, and $\ell\cap A_{i1}A_{i2}=C'_{i}$. Say $B_1A_{1i}\cap B_2A_{2i}=C_i$, and $C_1C_2C$ is collinear. It is easy to show$$[B_iA_{i1},B_iA_{i2};B_iX,B_iC'_i]=-1$$as $B_iX$ is the polar line of $C_i'$ wrt $\omega_i$. Thus we let $X_i=B_iX\cap C_1C_2$ and $Y_i=B_iC'_i\cap C_1C_2$, taking intersections with $C_1C_2$ we get$$[C_1,C_2;X_i,Y_i]=-1$$Let $D=B_1B_2\cap C_1C_2$. We then have $[C_1,C_2;D,C]=-1$;
 
we get a contradiction here by noticing $X_1,X_2$ is on the same "side" of $D$, while $Y_1,Y_2$ are necessarily on different "sides" of $C$ (which is because $C'_i$ is inside the segment $CA_{i1}$ for one $i$, and outside the segment for the other (which is becase $\ell$ must intersect with $A_{11}A_{21}$ inside it and Menelaus) and Menelaus). It is better to draw your own graph and see why it happens.


Thus we return to the original problem: say ellipses $E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4,E_5$ are all tangent to $E$ at two points. Say the tangent point of $E_i$ is $A_{i1},A_{i2}$, and $E_i$ tangent to $E_{i+1}$ at $X_{i+3}$ (index mod 5). Denote $B_{i+3}=A_{i1}A_{i2}\cap A_{i+1,1}A_{i+1,2}$ and $C_{i}=B_{i+2}X_{i+2}\cap B_{i+3}X_{i+3}$. Finally denote $Y_i=X_{i+2}X_{i+3}\cap B_{i+2}B_{i+3}$.
 
By Lemma1 we should prove$$\prod_{i}\frac{C_iX_{i+2}}{C_iX_{i+3}}=1$$But by Menelaus we have$$\prod_i \frac{C_iX_{i+2}}{X_{i+2}B_{i+2}}\frac{B_{i+2}Y_i}{Y_iB_{i+3}}\frac{B_{i+3}X_{i+3}}{X_{i+3}C_i}=\prod_i1=1$$The $\prod\limits_i \frac{B_{i+3}X_{i+3}}{B_{i+2}X_{i+2}}$ term cancels, so we shall only prove$$\prod_i \frac{B_{i+2}Y_i}{Y_iB_{i+3}}=1$$This led to the following lemmas:

Lemma3
For points $X,Y$ and ellipse $\omega$, denote a number $F_\omega(X,Y)$ as follows: construct tangents $XA$ and $YB$ with tangent points $A$ and $B$ to $\omega$, such that $XA$ and $YB$ lie on the same side of $XY$. Say $AB\cap XY=Z$, then $F_\omega(X,Y)=\frac{XZ}{ZY}$.
https://cdn.artofproblemsolving.com/attachments/f/7/c10e9313cb323d71bc574b2130da1380428849.png 
If $\omega$ and $\omega'$ intersects $XY$ at the same two points, then $F_\omega(X,Y)=F_{\omega'}(X,Y)$.

Proof
Say $XY$ intersects $\omega$ at $C,D$. We prove that $F_\omega(X,Y)=\sqrt{\frac{XC\cdot XD}{YC\cdot YD}}$. This is because it is true for circles, and stretching $\omega$ to become a circle does not change this statement because lengths on the same line are stretched equally.



Lemma4
Using notations from Lemma3, for a fixed ellipse $\omega$ there exists a funxtion $G_\omega(X)$ such that $F_\omega(X,Y)=\frac{G_\omega(X)}{G_\omega(Y)}$.

Proof
It is obvious that $F_\omega(X,Y)F_\omega(Y,X)=1$. It suffices to prove $F_\omega(X,Y)F_\omega(Y,Z)F_\omega(Z,X)=1$, so that picking any point $O$ and setting $G_\omega(X)=F_\omega(X,O)$ does the trick. But we can again stretch $\omega$ to a circle where $F_\omega(X,Y)F_\omega(Y,Z)F_\omega(Z,X)=1$ is obvious.


Hence$$\prod_i \frac{B_{i+2}Y_i}{Y_iB_{i+3}}=\prod_i F_{E_i}(B_{i+2},B_{i+3})=\prod_i F_E(B_{i+2},B_{i+3})=\prod_i\frac{G_E(B_{i+2})}{G_E(B_{i+3})}=1$$

Not an answer, but a generalization to OP's circle result, Lemma 2.

Consider an ellipse with center $O$ that has an internally doubly-tangent circle of radius $r$ (with touch-points $T$ and $T'$) and externally doubly-tangent ellipse with center $K$ (with touch-points $U$ and $V$). Specifically, writing $M$ for the midpoint of $UV$, we determine the enclosing ellipse by taking $K$ to be the dilation of $M$ in $O$ with scale factor $-\tan^2\kappa$ for some $\kappa > 0$. (When $\kappa=0$ the ellipses coincide, a situation we can ignore.)
Let the tangents to the circle (and inner ellipse) at $T$ meet the outer ellipse at $P$ and $Q$, and define $p:=|TP|$ and $q:=|TQ|$. Likewise, we have $p':=|T'P'|$ and $q':=|T'Q'|$ via the tangent at $T'$.
We can express $p/q$ and $p'/q'$ neatly using the standard coordinate parameterization of the ellipse. First, define $U$, $V$, $T$ and $T'$ by
$$U = (a \cos(\theta+\phi), b \sin(\theta+\phi) ) \qquad
V = ( a \cos(\theta-\phi), b \sin(\theta-\phi) ) \tag1$$
$$T = (a \cos\psi, b \sin\psi ) \qquad
T' = ( a \cos\psi, -b \sin\psi )$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the major and minor radii of the inner ellipse. Writing $e$ for the eccentricity of the inner ellipse, we can express the radius of the circle as
$$r^2=a^2(1-e^2)(1-e^2\cos^2\psi) = b^2 ( 1- e^2\cos^2\psi) \tag2$$
In any case, the parametric angles give us the following:
$$\frac{p}{q}=\frac{1-\sin\kappa\sin(\psi-\theta)}{1+\sin\kappa\sin(\psi-\theta)} \qquad
\frac{p'}{q'}=\frac{1-\sin\kappa\sin(\psi+\theta)}{1+\sin\kappa\sin(\psi+\theta)} \tag3$$
Interestingly, these ratios are independent of $\phi$. Also we see immediately the conditions for the ratios to reduce to $1$: (with appropriate quadrant restrictions) $\psi=\theta$ and $\psi=-\theta$.
Now, taking a cue from OP's lemma, we consider a more-symmetric expression by adding each ratio to its reciprocal ... or, rather the square roots thereof ... and calculate
$$\begin{align}
\left(\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}+\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}}\right)^2 &= \frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{p}+2=\frac{4}{1-\sin^2\kappa\sin^2(\psi-\theta)} \\[6pt]
\left(\sqrt{\frac{p'}{q'}}+\sqrt{\frac{q'}{p'}}\right)^2 &= \;\quad\cdots\quad\;
=\frac{4}{1-\sin^2\kappa\sin^2(\psi+\theta)} 
\end{align}\tag{4}$$
Of note: When $\theta$ is an odd multiple of $90^\circ$ (so that $UV$ is parallel to the major axis of the inner ellipse), these expressions match.
To connect this with OP's circular lemma, we'll note that we can relate our parameter $\kappa$ to the eccentricities of the inner and outer ellipses ($e$ and, say, $f$) directly, if inelegantly:
$$\cos\kappa = \frac{
    (2 - f^2) \sqrt{1 - e^2}
    - \sqrt{f^4 (1 - e^2) - e^4 (1 - f^2) \sin^22\theta}
   }{2 \sqrt{1 - f^2} (1 - e^2 \cos^2\theta)} 
\tag{5}$$
When the enclosing ellipse is a circle ($f=0$) and the inner one is not ($e\neq 0$), we find
$$\cos\kappa = \frac{
    2  \sqrt{1 - e^2}
    - \sqrt{-e^4\sin^22\theta}
   }{2(1 - e^2 \cos^2\theta)} 
\tag{5'}$$
The radical expression will be real if and only iff $\sin2\theta=0$, so that $\theta$ must be an odd multiple of $90^\circ$. (This is intuitively clear: For our enclosing ellipse to be a circle, chord $UV$ must be parallel to the major axis of the inner ellipse.) In this case, the formula reduces much further:
$$\cos\kappa = \sqrt{1 - e^2} \quad\to\quad \sin\kappa = e\tag{5''}$$
whereupon $(4)$ becomes
$$\left(\sqrt{\frac{p}{q}}+\sqrt{\frac{q}{p}}\right)^2 =\frac{4}{1-e^2\cos^2\psi} =\frac{4b^2}{r^2}\tag{4'}$$
(recalling $(2)$), recapturing OP's Lemma 2. $\square$
I have yet to find a good way to rewrite $(2)$ "non-parametrically" (ie, using lengths and/or angles in the figure rather than eccentric angles $\theta$ and $\psi$). Considering how messy it is to convert $\kappa$ via $(5)$, which still references $\theta$, there may not even be a "good" way. Or perhaps I've overlooked something obvious.
That's enough for now ...
